# Receiving unexpected indent with encryption script

Tags: python, encryption

So I've been working on this script to just create a simple encrypted message and write the cipher text to a file. I keep getting an error for "unexpected indent" on line 32 and I can't figure out why. I've taken 2 pieces of code I found online and tried to combine them to come up with a solution that would write cipher text to a file but I keep getting these indent errors even though it worked when the code was by itself.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import string
import base64
import time
#import modules
PADDING = '{'
BLOCK_SIZE = 32
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING
#prepare crypto method
EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)
#set encryption/decryption variables
loop=5
while loop==5:
    print '---->>>>))))mAmbA CiPH3r((((<<<<---- \n \n'
     #set up loop, so the program can be rerun again if desired without restarting
    option=raw_input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt a message?\nEncrypt: 1\nDecrypt: 2\n")
    if option=='1':
        letter=3
        while letter==3:
            secret = raw_input("Please Enter An Encryption Key {must be 16 characters long}: ")
            countTotal= (len(secret))
            if countTotal==16:
                cipher = AES.new(secret)
                letter=0
            else:
                print "Please Ensure The Key You Entered Is 16 Characters In Length\n"
                letter=3
                #this checks the encryption key to ensure it matches the correct length
        # encode a string
        data=raw_input("Please Enter Text You'd Like Encrypted: ")
        encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, data)
        print 'Encrypted String', encoded
    file1=raw_input("Please Enter The Path and File Name You'd Like to Write To: ")
    target = open("file1", 'w')
    target.truncate()
    target.write(encoded)
        options=raw_input("Would You Like To Encrypt/Decrypt Again? Y/N\n")
        if options=='y':
            loop=5
        if options=='n':
            loop=0

    if option=='2' :

        encoded=raw_input("Please Enter The Encoded String:\n")
        letter=3
        while letter==3:
            secret=raw_input("Please Enter The Decryption Key:\n")
            countTotal= (len(secret))
            #this checks the encryption key to ensure it matches the correct length
            if countTotal==16:
                cipher = AES.new(secret)
                letter=0
                decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encoded)
                print 'Decrypted string:', decoded
                options=raw_input("Would You Like To Encrypt/Decrypt Again? Y/N\n")
                if options=='y':
                    loop=5
                if options=='n':
                    loop=0
            else:
                print "Please Ensure The Key You Entered Is 16 Characters In Length\n"
                letter=3

if loop==0:
    print "Goodbye!!"
    time.sleep(2)
    exit
    #exits the program if desired by user
```

Comment: `options=raw_input....` and the following two ifs should not be indented, you asle never call `exit -> exit()`

Comment: So they shouldn't be indented at all?

Comment: no, dedent them and it will fix your error

Comment: It's still saying "unexpected indent" on line 32 which is `data=raw_input...`

Comment: Not if your code is as posted and fixed those lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to fix the indents when copying the text over. These five lines need to be unindented:

```
        options=raw_input("Would You Like To Encrypt/Decrypt Again? Y/N\n")
        if options=='y':
            loop=5
        if options=='n':
            loop=0
```

The easiest way to do this in IDLE is to make a selection that has at least part of all five lines, and use the keystroke `Control + [` or `command + [` on a mac.

Comment: Folliwing these steps exactly should work now.

Comment: @greenMamBa If you copy the text straight from your question and only apply the changes in this answer, the module compiles without any indent errors.

Comment: between you and Padraic I got it working. Thanks a ton!!!